# Resize on ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I currently have an AngularJS application embedded in an iframe which needs to be resized to avoid scrollbars. I've got a function in the app that calculates the height of the container and then resizes the iframe.

Currently I am using a directive (resizeAppPart) which will call the resize function on the last item in the scope.

Directive:

```
app.directive('resizeAppPart', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last) {
      Communica.Part.adjustSize();
    }
  }
});
```

Layout:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in filteredTasks = (tasks | filter:filters)" resize-app-part>                    
  <td><a href="{{spConfig.spHostUrl}}{{task.visit.ServerRelativeUrl}}/Lists/Actions/DispForm.aspx?ID={{task.Id}}">{{task.Task_x0020_Title}}</a></td>
  <td><span ng-repeat="user in task.assignees" ng-show="user.Title != ''">
  ...
</tr>
```

This works on the initial load but if I filter the list using any of the search boxes, the directive doesn't run so you either end up with a scrollbar or a few thousand pixels of whitespace - neither are ideal.

Is there a way to call the directive, or even the function directly, after the table is filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `$watch` , Use this:

```
app.directive('resizeAppPart', function ($timeout) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('$last',function(){
        Communica.Part.adjustSize();
    }

    scope.$watch(attrs.filterWatcher,function(){
       $timeout(function(){
         Communica.Part.adjustSize();
       },100)
    })
  }
});
```

And slight change in html this way

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:filters" resize-app-part filter-watcher={{filters}}>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work mostly although there are still some issues with the searching/filtering. As I enter a search term, the list filters down but doesn't resize, in order to resize the table I have to enter a search term plus some random characters so that 0 results are found - when I then delete the random characters the app resizes. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: @BenShort i edited my answers, and put also watchers on `filters`, please give it a try.